# JQuery - How can I write a case-insensitive 'Attribute Contains' selector?

Tags: jquery, attributes, selector, case-insensitive

I'm trying to write a userscript for YouTube that will select all videos on a page based on their titles, which are also set as the thumbnail images' `title` attribute.

The following works just fine, but it's case sensitive:

```
var videoTitle = "the";

$('img[title*="'+videoTitle+'"]').each(function() {

// stuff here

});
```

The selector above will match any video with "the" in the title, but not "The" or "THE", for example.

I did read that I could use `.filter()` to accomplish this somehow, but I'm not sure how that works, and I couldn't find an example that would fit my scenario successfully.

I tried something like this, based on an example I found on StackOverflow, but it doesn't work:

```
$('img[title]').filter(function(){return this.title.toLowerCase() == videoTitle}).each(function() {

// stuff here

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is adapted from a post by Karl Swedburg on the jQuery [docs page](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) for the 'Attributes Contains Selector'. It uses a RegEx and the `i` case insensitive switch along with the `filter` function  -

```
<img title="Star Wars"/>
<img title="Star Wars 2"/>
<img title="Star Wars 3"/>
<img title="Back To The Future"/>

var videoTitle = "star wars";
var re =  RegExp(videoTitle ,"i"); 
$('img[title]').filter(function() {
   return re.test(this.title);
}).each(function() {alert(this.title)});
```

The names of the three 'Star Wars' films should be alerted.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/FKBTx/3

Comment: Thank you. After I posted this question, the friend I wrote the script for said he doesn't need it to be case insensitive and took the script the way I had it.  Still, I tested this and it works great, and I'm positive it'll come in handy at some point.  Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way to preform the same filter just with a custom `data-` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Example -

```
$('img').filter(function(){
    return this.title.match(RegExp(videoTitle ,"i"))
}).each(function(){
        alert(this.title);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> using the filter option, just change the function to 
>   `return this.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(videoTitle) >= 0` 
>   otherwise it's only matching 'the', not things that contain 'the' (if that's what you want).
>   EDIT: Also, not sure if this.title is ok, but maybe if the above doesn't work, try $(this).attr('title')

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').filter(function (index) { return this.title.toLowerCase() === videoTitle; })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var videoTitle = "bla";
$('img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase() == videoTitle;
}).each(function() {
    // do something
});
```